# How do i convert JSON to CSV in NodeJS in a way that it does not contain the key values of JSON as first row?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern, json2csv

***My input :***

```
const jsonData = [{
            name : "Himank",
            age : 20
        },{
            name : "Manisha",
            age : 20
        },{
            name : "Sourav",
            age : 20
        }]
```

***Expected Output (using json2csv or josn-2-csv package)) :***

```
Himank, 20
Manisha, 20
Sourav, 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> header - Boolean, determines whether or not CSV file will contain a title column. Defaults to true if not specified.

```
;(()=> {

  const jsonData = [{
    name : "Himank",
    age : 20
  },{
    name : "Manisha",
    age : 20
  },{
    name : "Sourav",
    age : 20
  }];

  const fields = ['name', 'age'];
  const opts = { fields, header: false };
  
  try {
    const {Parser } = json2csv
    const parser = new Parser(opts);
    const csv = parser.parse(jsonData);
    console.log(csv);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

})()
```

```js
;(()=> {

  const jsonData = [{
    name : "Himank",
    age : 20
  },{
    name : "Manisha",
    age : 20
  },{
    name : "Sourav",
    age : 20
  }];

  const fields = ['name', 'age'];
  const opts = { fields, header: false };
  
  try {
    const {Parser } = json2csv
    const parser = new Parser(opts);
    const csv = parser.parse(jsonData);
    console.log(csv);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/json2csv@4.2.1"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```